# Difference between my application object and application context object

Tags: android

I am looking for information regarding writing my own application class. In many tutorials on the net I have seen the following code:

```
class myapp extends Application
{
    private static myapp mm;
    private Context context;

    public Context getContext()
    {
        return getApplicationContext();
    }

    public myapp getmyapp()
    {
        if(mm == null)
        mm = new myapp();
        return mm;
    }
}
```

What is the difference in getting object of `myapp` and `getApplicationContext` and where to use object of `myapp` and where to use context object. I just want to clear the concept of usage of these objects.

Answer (score 1):

that code is completely wrong:

```
public myapp getmyapp()
{
if(mm==null)
mm=new myapp();
return mm;
}
```

only the Android framework can instantiate the Application object. I mean, you can call `new` but the object won't be "connected" to the underlying framework

To have a static reference of the application object you should do as follows:

```
class MyApp extends Application{
//  I fixed the names to follow some Java convention
private static MyApp instance;

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      instance = this;
   }

public static MyApp getMyApp(){
    return instance;
}
```

Regarding the context, the code is not wrong, but simply doesn't make any sense. That's because the `Application` object already is the `application context`. So there's not need to ask for it.

Context is what gives Android apps access to resources, file system specific folders, permissions, etc (what I said about the Android framework creates it). The `Application` is one class that extends `Context`, other examples are `Activity` and `Service` classes.

I hope it's a bit clearer.

Comment: thanks for the same.does this means returning this or getapplicationcontext() from this class myapp would mean the same thing.

Comment: yes. the instance of `Application` and `getApplicationContext()` is the same thing, you can even cast it `((MyApp)getApplicationContext())`